# Is it possible to share a project between Xcode 4 and 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode5

I'm collaborating on a project using a git repository. Some contributors machines only run Xcode 4, but I need to upgrade to Xcode 5. Will this cause any conflicts or corruption or can Xcode handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were no changes done to project file so you can safely use it on both versions same time.
Xcode 5 might just prompt you for some automatic settings changes - so you should ignore that otherwise Xcode 4 might be asking again to revert those changes.